# Tracking an imported video without a visible floor- Can it be done?

Tags: tracking

Title says it all, really.

When tracking a shot, it asks you to pick 3 points to make a floor plane and it bases everything off that. Can you track a shot without a visible floor? I have a very tight close-up shot that spins even closer.

Comment: You can track whatever you want, but keep in mind that what makes successful 3D reconstruction is having enough trackers that show parallax, and that there is enough information on the frame to track, and still determine depth.   And yes, you can orient the 3D reconstruction in any axis. It would help if you show images of the shots you are dealing with and be specific on what is the specific issue you are struggling with.

Comment: Read the following  post: [how an I get better results when doing camera motion tracking](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)